# $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix such that $\mathrm{trace}(A)=0$ and $\mathrm{det}(A)=-1$. Is there a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ containing the eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ matrix such that $\mathrm{trace}(A)=0$ and $\mathrm{det}(A)=-1$. How to show that there is a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ containing the eigenvectors ?

From the given information I get $-1$ and $1$ are the eigenvalue of the matrix. Then how should I prove that there corresponding eigenvectors are linearly independent ?

Comment: Eigenvectors associated to different eigenvalues are always linearly independent of each other. If the proof has not already been given on your course, it would be instructive to look it up.

Comment: You should not say _the_ eigenvectors. There will be many bases containing only eigenvectors, but none that contain _all_ the eigenvectors (obviously, as there are infinitely many of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

The characteristic polynomial of $\;A\;$ is

$$p_A(x)=x^2-(\text{tr.}\,A)\,x+\det A\stackrel{\text{given}}=x^2-1$$

Thus (why?) the minimal polynomial of $\;A\;$ is *also* $\;x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)\;$ ...

Comment: I do not understand your hint. can you please elaborate .

Comment: @liesel: a square matrix over any field is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial can be decomposed (over the definition field) in a product of **different** linear polynomials. And, of course, the basic theorem: the characteristic and minimal polynomials of a (square) matrix have the same irreducible factors.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Actually I find that "basic theorem" a bit of a headache. You can get it by working over an algebraic closure, using Cayley-Hamilton, the easy fact that all eigenvalues are roots of the minimal polynomial, and (somewhat harder) that the minimal polynomial is unchanged under field extensions (as is the characteristic one), but that makes it hardly "basic" to me. Do you know a way to get it more directly (without extending the field)?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, I'm not sure about "more directly", yet I really think that someone messing around with diagonalization is rather likely to have studied it already..."Basic" here is from "important and far reaching", not "easy".

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y\neq 0$ be eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalues $\lambda, \mu$. Let $x$ and $y$ be linearly dependent, meaning that $x=\alpha y$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $\lambda \neq 0$.

Then $x=\frac{1}{\lambda}(\lambda x) = \frac{1}{\lambda}Ax =\frac{1}{\lambda}A(\alpha y)=\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}Ay = \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \mu y = \frac{\mu}{\lambda}x$. From $x=\frac\mu\lambda x$, you can conclute $\lambda = \mu,$ a contradiction.

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Where do you use the fact that $Tr(A)=0$ and $det(A)=-1$?

Comment: @Silent OP said: "From the given information I get $-1$ and $1$ are the eigenvalue of the matrix." and then asked "Then how should I prove that there corresponding eigenvectors are linearly independent ?". I gave a general proof that shows that eigenvectors corresponding to *different* eigenvalues must be independent.